# Unable to run 2 webservers in Docker

Tags: docker-container

This is my 1st post and first time am posting here

1. I just create Amazon EC2 instance with Amazon linux and run "yum update" (I enabled SSH port-22 and http port-80 in the process of creating instance).
2. I installed the docker package in this linux "yum install docker". and run the service "service docker start"-- It showing Active and running
3. Now here my doubt is " is it possible to create more than 1 webservers in Docker" If yes, Could you plz share the commands.
4. I created a container of nginx i.e "docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginxserver nginx" (It is  create container and installed)- It is created successfully and it is working in the browser, Ex:http://184.72.64.208:80.
5. And I created a container of httpd i.e "docker run -d -p 88:80 --name httpdserver httpd" (this webserver is not working) Ex:http://184.72.64.208:88.
6. The above containers are running "Docker ps"
7. In the above scenario one webserver is working fine(nginx) and another one is not working(httpd).

Could you plz help me to resolve this issue

Thankyou
Arjun

Could you plz help me to resolve this issue